# Macro to find and replace parts of excel links

Tags: vba, excel

Screenshot of example rows:
[image]

This is the macro that I first recorded with relative references:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -3).Range("A1:L1").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Replace What:="Billy Bob", Replacement:="Joanne Sue", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

I have a master spreadsheet linking to many other individual spreadsheets.

The values in D-N all respectively reference the same cell in the individually linked sheets like this:

```
='G:\WORK\Test folder\Test\Employees\[Billy Bob.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E$2
```

Column C's link references the value in column B to fill in the name of the link like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("G:\WORK\Test folder\Test\Employees\Billy Bob.xlsx",B3)
```

So I'm essentially trying to change the name section of each link in the row. So, if I were to enter another name into Column B, the macro or code would then take that name in B and add it to the hyperlink in C and all the sheet links in D-N.

Comment: You've not asked a question. What is it we can help you with?

Comment: I added an edit at the end to try and clarify.

Comment: I saw this question a short while ago and declined to attempt a response due to the lack of information. tbh, the most important piece of information is still missing; e.g. the **exact** `Address` and `Subaddress` parameters of the [Hyperlinks object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839966.aspx) or the syntax of the [HYPERLINK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333C7CE6-C5AE-4164-9C47-7DE9B76F577F) (whichever is being used).

Comment: Once that is determined, you can be advised as to whether to simply adjust formula(s) to use `B2` instead of `Billy Bob` or your code could be modified to work within a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro so that simply putting new name or modifying a name in column B would be sufficient to generate a new row of adapted formula(s) and/or hyperlink(s).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I've added my hyperlinks and the links to other sheets for reference.

Comment: @Jeeped not sure if you saw

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the names in Column B and each name has a worksheet by that name. So this will create hyperlinks to Range A1 in those sheets. Be sure to replace d`s:\temp\hyper.xlsxd` with the actual path to your workbook.

```
Sub MakeHyperlinksColumnC()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim nm As String

    For x = 2 To ActiveSheet.Columns("C").Cells.Count
        Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Columns("C").Cells(x)
        If Not IsEmpty(aCell.Offset(0, -1)) Then
            nm = aCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            aCell.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""[s:\temp\hyper.xlsx]'" & nm & "'!A1"",""" & nm & """)"
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I think this will work better than search and replace. Also it skips the first row and exits on the first blank cell.

**ANOTHER METHOD**

Actually you don't need code at all; just use a formula like this in C2 then copy down:

```
=HYPERLINK("[s:\temp\hyper.xlsx]'"&B2&"'!A1",B2)
```